# Invalid value when getting purchase subscriptions

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to call **GET** https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token endpoint of google play developer api to get the information about the purchased subscription.But, everytime I  receive the below error message when I call this endpoint. Did anyone get this error before ?

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

Comment: I catch the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: Nope, I dropped working on my project.

Comment: your token is wrong, I actually purchase and get purchaseToken in the result. paste it in token and it worked

Answer (score -1):

You are not formatting your request properly. An HTTP code 400 means that the syntax you used for the request was incorrect, and so the server didn't know how to handle it. Re-check your GET request code to make sure it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I catch the same problem.  every time error show. Did you solve it?